# How to remove white space below footer

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to remove the white space below the footer as I have just realised. I have put the HTML code below and you can view the rest of the code on Pastebin, which I have enclosed the link for:

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center foot">
<div class="social">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitch"></a>
    <br><br>
    <hr class="dark-line">
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn">Subscibe</button>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>SUBSCRIBE TO THE THUNDER STRUCK MAILING LIST</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Welcome to the Thunder Struck Games Subscription Management page. Thunder Struck mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all the updates.</p>
                <button id="myBtn">Manage Your Account</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="link" href="#">Support</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Careers</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Mouthoff</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Press</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Corporate</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Privacy</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Cookies</a>&nbsp
    <a class="link" href="#">Legal</a>
    <br><br>
    <div class="copyrights">
        <p class="white-txt">© 2018 Thunder Struck Games
            <br><br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jpYeX7Gm)

[image: White space at the bottom of footer]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You can try to put this in your footer style `bottom: 0px;`

Comment: did you remove all margins from the body?
Also it seems like you have one closed `</div> ` too much at the end of your code, at least jsfiddle says so.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, could be two things, `<p class="white-txt">` or `<body>` default margins.

Try this

**CSS**

```
body, html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

**OR/AND**

```
.white-txt {
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wxpd915t/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, It was <p class="white-txt">

Comment: @KyleLogan, a vote will be appreciated (answer is useful). thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you have two br tags in the p tag with the class of "white-txt".
let me know if that works for you cheers.

Comment: You do not really provide a solution, though you are probably on track concerning the problem. You could turn this into a more assertive answer, by [edit]ing and phrasing a conditional answer, like "If the problem is that ... then the solution is to ..., because ...". An explained clear answer like that has better chances of being appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure, Divjot. I am waiting eagerly for you to act upon the insight I provided.